# Get entity name from Core Data record stored in Cloudkit

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, cloudkit, ios14

I have a Core Data Model with 3 entities: Employee, Athlete, and Therapist. Employee is an abstract entity, and as such I've marked Employee as the other two entity's parent in Xcode. The Codegen for each entity is set to `Class Definition`. Right now I'm writing logic that...

1. Fetches all Employee records **[working]**
2. Loops over each record **[working]**
3. Gets the record's entity name
4. Displays a different SwiftUI view based on the entity name

I'm stuck on 3. I've read through [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/mirroring_a_core_data_store_with_cloudkit/reading_cloudkit_records_for_core_data?language=objc) and see that Cloudkit adds an attribute to each record called `CD_entityName` containing the appropriate String ("Athlete" or "Therapist") for the entity name defined in Core Data..but I'm still confused. How do I get at the record's entity name and use it to inform my View logic?

Since `CD_entityName` exists in CloudKit's representation of the data model, do I need to also create an attribute for `CD_entityName` in my Core Data model?

Below is my `ContentView.swift` file. When I try to build the app I get an error saying Employee has no member 'CD_entityName'.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Employee.date_added, ascending: false)], animation: .default)
    private var allEmployees: FetchedResults<Employee>
    
    // * Body * //
    var body: some View {
            
            List {
                
                ForEach(allEmployees) { employee in

                    switch employee.CD_entityName {
                        case "Athlete":
                            AthleteRowView(athlete: employee as! Athlete)
                        case "Sound":
                            TherapistRowView(therapist: employee as! Therapist)
                        default:
                            print("Error: Unknown entityName for record")
                    }
                }
            }
        
    } // end Body
    
} // end ContentView
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
switch employee.entity.name {
    case "Athlete":
        AthleteRowView(athlete: employee as! Athlete)
    case "Sound":
        TherapistRowView(therapist: employee as! Therapist)
    default:
        EmptyView()
}
```